# How can I add additional data sources to an Acumatica email Notification Template?

Tags: acumatica

I'm modifying a Shipment Confirmation report and associated email Notification Template.  By default on the report, I have access to some Sales Order information, but I don't see how I can get down to things like default salesperson default contact information (phone/email etc) and to the SO Line.  (I'm looking to print an updated order summary with qty shipped total/qty backordered for each SO Line)

How can I add these additional data sources to the Notification Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add additional data to the Notification Template by adding a new view to the SOShipmentEntry_Extension graph.

To get SO Lines:

```
public PXSelectJoin<SOLine, 
        InnerJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<SOLine.orderType, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderType>, And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr>>>>,
        Where<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>, 
        And<SOOrderShipment.shipmentType, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentType>>>>> SOLines;
```

It doesn't show up in the listed datafields in the Template GUI, but it's accessible once I fiddled with the naming enough.